# How to create a directed graph from an array of items?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have an array of objects.

```
input = [
    {id:1,  from:h, to:l},
    {id:2,  from:b, to:e},
    {id:3,  from:p, to:q},
    {id:4,  from:e, to:h},
    {id:5,  from:e, to:g},
    {id:6,  from:l, to:m},
    {id:7,  from:m, to:k},
    {id:8,  from:k, to:i},
    {id:9,  from:g, to:i},
    {id:10, from:i, to:b}
]
```

The items in the array are sorted by an attribute called `id`.

The attribute `id` is unique.

Nodes in the graph should be connected by the `from` and `to`
attributes of each item in the array.

Example (not based in the above array):

```
{id:1, from:a, to:b} --> {id:2, from:b,to:c} --> {id:3, from:c, to:a}
```

The output of the algorithm should be this:

```
output = [
    {id:1,  from:h, to:l, next: [object with id = 6]},
    {id:2,  from:b, to:e, next: [object with id = 4, object with id = 5]},
    {id:3,  from:p, to:q, next: [null]},
    {id:4,  from:e, to:h, next: [object with id = 1]},
    {id:5,  from:e, to:g, next: [object with id = 9]},
    {id:6,  from:l, to:m, next: [object with id = 7]},
    {id:7,  from:m, to:k, next: [object with id = 8]},
    {id:8,  from:k, to:i, next: [object with id = 10]},
    {id:9,  from:g, to:i, next: [object with id = 10]},
    {id:10, from:i, to:b, next: [object with id = 2]}
]
```

So, the final directed graph should look like this:

[image]

Comment: So you have a list of edges that represents a directed graph datastructure. What is your question? How to render it graphically?

Comment: I can tell you that your picture is incorrect. The labels of the nodes should be the lower case letters. The id is the identifier of the edges.

Comment: Thanks @wvdz, what I want to get is a list, set or whatever collection is more appropriate of the same objects within the array, each pointing to another object or objects based on the `from` and `to` attributes.

Comment: Your problem is that your interpretation of that data structure is flawed. Your suggested output doesn't make much sense, and your original list of edges is a perfectly fine representation of a directed graph. Do you understand the difference between a node and an edge?

Comment: Hi @wvdz, sorry for the late replay. Yes, I understand the difference between those. However, in my original list I don't think it is a graph (yet) because the `from` and `to` attributes are plain `String` values, what I think I need is to add an additional attribute/property to each item in the original list, this additional attribute will point to one or more items within the original list where the `from` property of those is equal to the `to` attribute of my current item. Please, let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your original datastructure is a list of edges and is a fairly standard way to represent a graph datastructure. I think you are confusing the edges with nodes. In your list, the id uniquely identifies an edge, and the lowercase letters uniquely identify nodes.

Graphviz is a nice notation language for graphs. Translated to graphviz, your graph can be written like this:

```
digraph G {
h -> l
b -> e
p -> q
e -> h
e -> g
l -> m
m -> k
k -> i
g -> i
i -> b
}
```

You can use an online tool like http://www.webgraphviz.com/ to render this graphically. This will give a result like below. As you can see, this is quite different from the graph you drew.

[image]